# URL encoding with polish letters

Tags: php

This is my lines of code:

```
            $file = basename($plik, ".pdf");
            $pdf = 'pliki/dopobrania/pdf/';
            $dopobrania.='
            <div class="dopobrania_pdf'.($index==0?'
active':'').'">
                    <a href="'.$pdf.$plik.'" target=_blank>'.$file.'</a>
            </div>
            ';
            $index++;
        }
    }
```

the $file have a letters "śćł" etc.. How to encode it when I click on the link?

Comment: Have you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Comment: If server, PHP and headers are all properly configured to use `UTF-8`, there is no need to encode anything that is only a label. If you want it to work as a URL, you have to `url_encode` it.

Comment: NEVER use any other encoding anywhere than `UTF-8`!!! You will go crazy if you do, trust me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `urlencode` the link:

```
<a href="'.urlencode($pdf.$plik).'" target=_blank>'.$file.'</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about php's built-in function [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/urlencode)?

```
<a href="<?php echo urlencode($pdf.$plik); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $file; ?></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Also a small tip if you use notepad ++ go to format and covert to UTF-8. This helped me while ago. Apply this to your $plik generator